# Visual studio not offering suggestions for class members for ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm following a video guide regarding building my first app using ASP.Net MVC in a Visual Studio 2017 IDE.
I'm having an issue with the coloring & quick suggestions by the compiler.
Here is how it looks on the video I'm following, and the second image shows how my screen looks.
Please assist me with the situation, thanks!

[First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmm41.png)
[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es72R.png)

Comment: As long as there are no wavey red lines I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: There must be different theme of visual studio, or it could be customized.

Comment: @ste-fu thats the spirit! :p

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the project(after adding the model) and then the intellisense would work after adding the following in the view.

```
@model List<Customers>
```

i.e.

```
@model List<yourmodelsnamespace.Customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not an error or problem of the codes. I think you have another theme.
and for suggestions, Sometimes it happens. you can use "  Ctrl+J  " to check it.
and maybe you need to update your visual studio. something like this happened to me and after I updated it solved